# foreign keys between tables: Buildings and Activities have Addresses

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys

I have 3 entities:

- buildings
- activities
- addresses

I don't know how to put foreign keys between tables.

Buildings are located at addresses.
Activities are performed at addresses (one address at a time).

But I want one address table.

Consider the next attributes:

```
Buildings(id, phone, email, image, comments)
```

Should I put address_id?

```
Activities(id, description)
```

Should I put address_id?

```
Addresses(id, street, city, state, postcode)
```

Or should I put center_id and activity_id?

Answer (score 1):

You should use **address_id** both in buildings and activities tables.
Address is unique, while many buildings and many activities can be located to the same address!!

Comment: With your answer there could be 2 or more buildings referencing the same address_id no? I don't think your answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies that multiple buildings can be located at the same address - is this what you want? If so, just normalize it accordingly:

The `Address` is your 'root entity':

```
ADDRESS(address_id,street,city,state,postcode)
```

A `Building` can be located at exactly one `Address`, so include a reference to `Address`, a foreign key:

```
BUILDING(building_id,phone,email,image,comments,address_id)
```

An activity is performed at exactly one address, references to `Address` by foreign key:

```
ACTIVITY_ID(activity_id,description,address_id)
```

Maybe you should think about whether:

- a street number is missing in the address?
- should having more than one building at a given address be possible?
- more than one address for a given building is possible (yes, I've seen this)?
- a separate `ADDRESS` table is really necessary (see above questions)?

Answer (score 0):

Alex, you should have the IDs in both tables, as you're saying in your question. There is no need to have them in separate tables as actually the address of a building will be where an activity will be performed, right?

If you are worried about two buildings having the same location then add a uniq index in the address_id column of the buildings table.

Moving a bit forward. Can you have an address without a building? If that is the case, then you could even add the address data (columns) to the buildings table. Because it would be a one-to-one relationship and no other entity would need to use the address table but the buildings one. That way you would get rid of the addresses table